# iOS UIButton does not show title property when a specific unicode

Tags: ios

As mention in the title. I would like to set title to UIBUtton with a single character with enough content space but I couldn't. But I could do with UILabel with the same character. Anyone has a solution? Below is my viewDidLoad() method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
```

//      var aChar = "\u0EB8"
        var aChar = "T"

```
    myButton.setTitle(aChar, forState:.Normal)

    myLabel.text = aChar
}![enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Did you try something like this:     [myButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aChar] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Your code works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[myButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aChar] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

I will list it as an answer so you can accept it. Might help someone else as well :)